# Module installed but not found in import file

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

So I am trying to train MaskRCNN on my custom dataset of floorplans. I have used the MaskRCNN-TF2 repository (https://github.com/ahmedfgad/Mask-RCNN-TF2) and have used the following blog as a guide: https://engineering.matterport.com/splash-of-color-instance-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-and-tensorflow-7c761e238b46.

I am trying to train on my custom dataset, but I get the following error regarding the file model.py;

```
C:\Users\XXX\MaskTF2\mrcnn\model.py:2363: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if os.name is 'nt':
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\XXX\MaskTF2\samples\balloon\floorplan.py", line 50, in <module>
    from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils

  File "C:\Users\XXX\MaskTF2\mrcnn\model.py", line 19, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I am trying to run the code in an anaconda environment (called mask) with the following packages installed:

```
tensorflow                2.0.0           gpu_py36hfdd5754_0
tensorflow-base           2.0.0           gpu_py36h390e234_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.0.0              pyh2649769_0
tensorflow-gpu            2.0.0                h0d30ee6_0
```

Does anybody know why this error appears? As it is clear I have installed tensorflow in my environment.

Comment: Check your python path.

Comment: What do you mean with my path? I have my current directory linked to the map balloon with in there the file floorplan.py, the other file model.py is in another map of MaskTF2. 

I have tried putting the model.py file in the balloon map as well, but to no avail

Comment: Execute this command "which python" and check that python you are using is from the conda environment.

Comment: Make sure you have activated anaconda environment before executing the python file. and also make sure Tensorflow environment variables are set properly. Thanks!